# GitHub API - Highlighting Code

Tags: php, curl, github-api

I'm using cURL in PHP to search through code on GitHub. I have everything working except one small option that i cannot figure out how to do.

I have passed the `header: Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.text-match+json` into cURL just fine, which gives me the extra `[text_match]` section like so:

```
{
"text_matches": [
{
  "object_url": "https://api.github.com/repositories/167174/contents/src/attributes/classes.js?ref=825ac3773694e0cd23ee74895fd5aeb535b27da4",
  "object_type": "FileContent",
  "property": "content",
  "fragment": ";\n\njQuery.fn.extend({\n\taddClass: function( value ) {\n\t\tvar classes, elem, cur, clazz, j, finalValue",
  "matches": [
    {
      "text": "addClass",
      "indices": [
        23,
        31
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "object_url": "https://api.github.com/repositories/167174/contents/src/attributes/classes.js?ref=825ac3773694e0cd23ee74895fd5aeb535b27da4",
  "object_type": "FileContent",
  "property": "content",
  "fragment": ".isFunction( value ) ) {\n\t\t\treturn this.each(function( j ) {\n\t\t\t\tjQuery( this ).addClass( value.call( this",
  "matches": [
    {
      "text": "addClass",
      "indices": [
        80,
        88
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

]
}

I use the `$item['text_matches][$i]['fragment']` to refer to the line of code that i'm searching for.

What i was hoping to do was explicitly state what exact line in the file where the code fragment begins.

Originally, i thought `$item['text_matches][$i]['matches]['indices']` was what i was looking for, but this is not the case.

So, how would i go about getting the exact line, because i dont see it within the json dataset.

Comment: Whys `indices` not the case?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone because they show position of a search text in a `fragment`?

Comment: As an example, `"fragment": ".isFunction(` from the second match, if you navigate to the file, youd see that this line of code is visible on L18,L61,L105. Where as, the indices for this example are at 80,88.

Comment: indices = chars not line numbers. https://3v4l.org/IlN8N

Comment: You would need to make multiple calls, for example to `object_url` then grab `download_url` then use the fragment to match the line, and the indices to match the text, or use text.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Right, i see now. i just need to search the raw file for the line it starts on.

Comment: or use the `content` prop on `object_url`, its the file contents base64'ed so that will save a call.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I only needed one extra api call to get to the raw file, and unfortunately i dont really get how to manipulate the content string. Edit: i just tried base64_decode() on the content string, it spits the file out, problem is it also redirects to the index page in my project?